# DbMetal chokes on repeated foreign key references in SQLite - any ideas?

Tags: database, sqlite, orm, dblinq, dbmetal

I've been struggling to get DbMetal to process my SQLite database. I finally isolated the problem. It won't allow a table to have two foreign key references to the same column.

For example, a SQLite database with these two tables will fail:

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Name TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Match
(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    WinnerPersonId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Person(Id),
    LoserPersonId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Person(Id)
);
```

I get this error:

> DbMetal: Sequence contains more than one matching element

If I get rid of the second foreign key reference, no error occurs.

So, this works:

```
CREATE TABLE Match
(
    Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    WinnerPersonId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Person(Id),
    LoserPersonId INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

But I really need both "person" columns to reference the Person table.

I submitted a [bug report](http://groups.google.com/group/dblinq-bugs/browse_thread/thread/15d0fe0141c284b0) for this, but I could use a workaround in the meantime. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had the same problem and created a patch. I've also posted it at your [bug report](http://groups.google.com/group/dblinq-bugs/browse_thread/thread/15d0fe0141c284b0). For others, you can find the patch here: http://pastebin.com/VhNptMqp.

Comment: Great, FrozenCow, thanks! Is there any way I can get my hands on a compiled .exe or do I have to download the source and paste in?

Comment: I ended up downloading the source and putting in your fixes. Worked like a charm. Thanks again for you help.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't get notified about your comments. Good to hear it all worked out.